# how to add, edit and delete the password saved in array outside the web root directory using a PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which submit data including password for each data in the database table(MySQL), but I decided to keep the password outside the web root as an array of password in a config.php file instead of keeping them in the database.

Note: This is not a login password but it will work smtp mailing, so the other configuration are kept in the database except the password look at the table structure here:

```
id |email              |smtpsecure |otherconfigurationcolumn...|foreign_id
1  |mailer@example.com |ssl        |...                        |1
```

The config.php file

```
<?php
    return [
    1 => 'the_password_for_the_given_id'
];

?>
```

A php  code which fetch and compare the password from file and that in the database  look like

```
 $fetched_id = $db -> prepare('SELECT id FROM mymailingtable WHERE foreign_id = ?');
    $fetched_id -> execute([$foreign_id]);

    if($fetched_id -> rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $id = $fetched_id -> fetch();

        $get_all_passwords_from_outside_webroot = require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/allpasswords.php';

        if(array_key_exists($id['id'], $passwords) === true)
        {
            $password = $get_all_passwords_from_outside_webroot[$id['id']];
```

Then I fetch the other mailing configuration and append the above password....
The trouble is how to add,edit and delete the password via form to file, assume I have already created a form and post the password via form field how to write it in the file and what if i have more password for more data

I want to add the password via form by detecting last inserted id in the above table since the id is auto incremented, and by now I'm adding the password manually, is there a way to add, edit and delete the password in that file or any suggestion please!.

If you don't understand:

I mean how can I add a new password based on the new added data in the database table above and the password in the given file as an array without key conflict or repetition and what if i want to update or delete

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stucK?

Comment: Instead of trying to create an array yourself, either store the data as `JSON`, which you then can read out/store with `json_encode` / `json_decode` or if you really want to use an array, look at `var_export`

Comment: @Nico Haase, for now i can add, edit and delete the data in a database only that is not a big issue for me, I want when I add, or edit or delete and the data in the config file which resemble the id and the array key to be modified or when i add new data then the password must be written in the config file with the last id not automatically

Comment: Editing PHP code dynamically isn't a trivial task. You need a PHP parser for that, and it feels an overkill for this use case. It's easier to just recreate the file from scratch every time. You could have a template that starts with a `Auto-generated file, changes will be overwritten` comment. But, as already  mentioned, an even easier approach is to use a data file rather than code. Last but not least, beware of concurrency—it's hard to get right.

Comment: @ Álvaro González
how?

Comment: @adttmkbttmkb See my comment